CrossEntropyLoss on PyTorch LSTM model with one classification per timestep
I am trying to make an LSTM model that will detect anomalies in timeseries data. It takes 5 inputs and produces 1 boolean output (True/False if anomaly is detected). The anomaly pattern will usually be between 3 - 4 timesteps in a row. Unlike most LSTM examples where they are forecasting to predict future data, or classifying a whole sequence of data, I am trying to have a True/False detection flag output at every timestep (True at the last timestep point in the patter if it is detected).
Unfortunately it seems like CrossEntropyLoss doesn't allow for anything more than 1D output tensors, and in this case it will be 2D [num sequences, length of sequence with boolean data]
Here is some example code of what I am trying to produce:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

# Define LSTM classifier model
class LSTMClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size):
        super(LSTMClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out

# Input - 100 examples containing 5 data points per timestep (where there are 10 timesteps)
X_train = np.random.rand(100, 10, 5)
# Output - 100 examples containing 1 True/False output per timestep to match the input
y_train = np.random.choice(a=[True, False], size=(100, 10))  # Binary labels (True or False)

# Convert data to PyTorch tensors
X_train_tensor = torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float32)
y_train_tensor = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.bool)

# Define model parameters
input_size = X_train.shape[2] # 5 inputs per timestep
hidden_size = 4 # Pattern we are trying to detect is usually 4 timesteps long
num_layers = 1
output_size = 1 # True/False

# Instantiate the model
model = LSTMClassifier(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size)

# Define loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Train the model
num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(X_train_tensor)
    loss = criterion(outputs, y_train_tensor)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item()}')

# Test the model
X_test = np.random.rand(10, 10, 5) # Generate some test data - same dimensions as input
X_test_tensor = torch.tensor(X_test, dtype=torch.float32)
with torch.no_grad():
    predictions = model(X_test_tensor)
    predicted_outputs = torch.argmax(predictions, dim=1)
    print("Predicted Outputs:", predicted_outputs)

Do I need to re-shape the output (or make the number of outputs from the LSTM equal to the sequence length), or perhaps use a different loss function, or a model other than LSTM?

I don't follow what you are trying to do on a conceptual level, but I can help you diagnose why torch is complaining.
Issue #1 - Incorrect Matrix Shapes
For any given observation and prediction (n=1), cross entropy loss will need the real class value y (1,1) and the prediction probabilities for all classes (in this case:- (1,2).
In each epoch you are feeding the model a tensor of shape (100, 10, 15) and outputting logits of shape (100, 1). If 100 refers to the number of individual examples - then I found this output shape odd. If for each observation you would like to a binary prediction, an output shape of (100, 2) would make more sense.
That is because internally nn.CrossEntropyLoss will generate the probabilities for each class. For example, the following would work
# note the dtypes
outputs = torch.randn(100, 2, requires_grad=True)  # logits
y_train_tensor = torch.randint(low=0, high=1, size=(100,))  # labels

output = loss(outputs, y_train_tensor)

Issue #2 - labels dtype
You've also set the dtype of y_train_tensor to bool. I don't think that torch converts this internally, so best to use a numeric dtype such as torch.int.
Now, to actually solve the problem (which of the tensors to reshape) will depend upon your task and what the model output shape represents.
Hope this helps.

Thanks for your answer, I would like to take the 5 input values, and make a boolean output (True/False) at each point in time - not classify each set of example data. End goal is flagging specific time points on a graph where the 5 inputs match something. Arbitrary example: if all 5 inputs are the same number, output should be True, otherwise False.

Not sure if I follow. So if your input shape is (100, 10, 5), corresponding to (example, time_step, data_point), your end goal is to have an output matrix of shape (100, 10, 1), by transforming the data point values to True or False depending on if they all have the same number at each time step? If that's the case, a NN is unnecessary.

That's correct, however the relationship is quite complicated between the input features and the pattern is normally a bunch of timesteps long, with the point flagged True usually being at a specific peak of the pattern
